# Relatives before the noun

Tags: relative-clauses

> This is a vast, exciting and **some say** quixotic project.
> (Cambridge dictionary)

I can understand the meaning that only some people say it is quixotic. But the structure is somewhat rare, because in general, the relative clause comes after the noun ("project which some say (is) quixotic").
Is it because the phrase "some say" itself is special that it can appear in this position? Can I put any other phrases here:

vast, exciting and **David says** quixotic project
vast, exciting and **some agree** quixotic project
vast, exciting and **some find/think** quixotic project

Comment: There's no relative clause. "Some say" is simply a supplementary adjunct, rather like an interpolation.

Comment: Your example itself isn't very idiomatic, because ***vast*** and ***exciting*** are *positive* attributes, but ***quixotic*** (regardless of whether you want it to mean ***impractical*** or ***unpredictable***) is a *negative* attribute, which doesn't sit well with conjunction ***and*** (regardless of whether ***some say*** or syntactic equivalent is included). The natural conjunction is probably "contrastive" ***but***, but in practice I'd probably draw attention to that contrast using a few more words. The terseness of the example doesn't appeal to me, with "underplayed" inclusive contrast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your examples work. But they and your original could do with some commas—or dashes—(or parentheses) to set off the phrases in question à la “It was a dark and, **some say,** stormy night.”